# How can I move data directly from one Google Cloud Storage project to another?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

How can I move data directly from one Google Cloud Storage project to another?
I understand how to upload and how to download, but I want to transfer directly between projects.

Comment: "Projects" are a construct to organise tools... Objects live in buckets regardless. So you'll have to just copy it from bucket to bucket.

Comment: @HannahS If there's an answer that worked for you, please mark it as the accepted answer. This rewards the author and helps other people who have the same question.

Answer (score 58):

To copy any single object from one GCS location to another, you can use the copy command. This can be done from either of our public APIs, or by using the command-line client, [*gsutil*](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil).

With *gsutil*, the [`cp command`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) could be used like this:

```
gsutil cp gs://bucket1/obj gs://bucket2/obj2
```

**Edit**:
Since I wrote this, the [Google Cloud Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/) has become available, which is good for copying whole buckets between GCS projects, or for copying whole buckets from S3 into GCS. You can find out more [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/).

Comment: This seems to copy between two buckets in the same project.  Do you have an example of copying from one project to another?

Comment: The buckets in this example can be in different projects. There is nothing in this example that mention specific project.

Comment: The problem is in the credentials, you must have credentials with the access to the both projects.

Comment: How do you check that?

Comment: @JohnAndrews what worked for me is: try doing the `gsutil cp` command as detailed elsewhere in this question, and it gives you an error telling you what service account is lacking permissions.  Then, you add that one to the bucket's permissions (I used role Storage Object Admin) and try again.

Comment: I ended up using: `gsutil -m rsync -pPr PROD-15745 gs://eci_staging_transfer/PROD-15745` where _PROD-15745_ was the folder to copy, and _eci_staging_transfer_ the bucket name.  [rsync docs.](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync)  More useful `gsutil` cmds: `gsutil cp dmesg.txt gs://my_bucket/` (just copy a file), `gsutil ls -al gs://my_bucket/` (list files there), `gsutil rm gs://my_bucket/dmesg.txt` (delete a file).  The `ls` output format is different from what you're used to.  You can always check the bucket contents via the GCP console GUI, too.

Comment: worked for me. Two different projects where my user had access. The copy of 600mb took less than a second. (while an upload to the destination project from our 4G connection was taking ages (crowded tech event))

Comment: is it possible to transfer from one bucket to another where for both buckets, there are separate credentials/owners.

Comment: The thing that's annoying to me about the Google Cloud Transfer Service is that it doesn't seem to inherit the permissions of the user. So it becomes something separate that you are permissioning in IAM and to make it usable by a lot of people you might need to assign it overly broad permissions.

Answer (score 35):

Open The Web console [Storage > Tranfer](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/transfer) to create a new transfer.

Select the source bucket you want to copy from. Just like [cratervale menitoned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39008449/8709030) just above here, bucket identifiers are [*globally* unique](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming#considerations) *(this is key to the solution*). So once you get to the destination part of the transfer form, you can write/paste the target bucket right in it's text input. Even if that bucket is from another project. It will show you a green icon once the target has been verified being an existing bucket. You can continue the form again to finalise your setup.

Once you started the transfer from the form, you can follow it's progress by hitting the refresh button on top of the console.

Comment: As of 2022, this is the fastest and easier way to go, thanks a lot. I was able to transfer hundreds of GB in seconds.

Comment: @eexit do you know if this works to move from GCS to Google Drive?

Answer (score 29):

This is [one of] the quickest ways to do it:

```
gsutil -m rsync -r gs://bucket-source/dir gs://bucket-destination/dir
```

Please note that `/dir` refers to a directory [or sub-directories e.g. `/dir1/dir2`] under the main bucket. It does not refer to a file name. If you try to transfer individual files, you will get an error.

See more configuration options in the [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync).

However, there are a few things you should setup properly to prevent issues. Here's a setup list:

1. Create a service account for your source bucket [from the source project, `Google Cloud Console -> IAM -> Service Account`]. Use Storage Admin as Role. Make sure you create a JSON key and download this to a safe place on your computer. Take note of the path to this file [e.g. `path/to/source-service-account.json`] as you will need it later.
2. Create a service account for your destination bucket [same process as above, but make sure to switch to the destination project]. You may download JSON key if you need to use it later, but this is optional.
3. Add the service account of the source bucket [created in 1. above] to the destination bucket [From the destination project, `Google Cloud Console -> Storage -> Browser`, then click on the main bucket, then click on the *Permissions* tab, then click on the "Add Members" button. Add the email address of the source bucket service account in the text box provided, then give Storage Admin permissions]
4. If you're using gcloud cli [command line tools], are logged in to the source project, you can run the `gsutil` command now. However, if you're not properly authenticated, you might get access permission errors. You can authenticate using the service account file [the one you created and downloaded in 1. above] by running the following command `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/path/to/source-service-account.json`. Once you do this, you will be logged in to GCP using the service account. You may now run the `gsutil` command to transfer your files.
5. When you're done, check your login status using `gcloud auth list`. And, you can switch accounts using `gcloud config set account 'ACCOUNT'`

Cheers.

Comment: Question. If I copy from bucket->bucket within the same project and region do I pay? What if I copy from bucket->bucket within same region but different project, do I pay? Who can answer this for me?

Answer (score 17):

If you want to use the console follow @Martin van Dam's answer.

If you want to use the shell :

Step 1. Open `google cloud shell`

Step 2. Run `gcloud init` & follow the process to connect to the cloud project that bucket1 belongs to.

Step 3. run `gsutil cp -r gs://[bucket1]/* gs://[bucket2]`

*You are done!*

---

*Now there's a catch! If both bucket belongs to the same project these steps will work flawlessly. But in case both buckets don't belong to the `same project` or the `same google cloud account`. It won't work. You need to fix the permissions.

*If they belong to the same GCP account :*

Go to `Storage` > `Browser` > Select bucket > Options > `Edit bucket permissions` > `add member` > insert the `service account email id` for the project that the bucket2 belongs to > set role to Storage.`Storage Admin` > Save. Then run `gstuil cp` command.

*If they belong to the separate GCP accounts :*

Go to `Storage` > `Browser` > Select bucket > Options > `Edit bucket permissions` > `add member` > insert the `gmail id` which the project that the bucket2 belongs to > set role to Storage.`Storage Admin` > Save. Then run `gstuil cp` command.

Comment: I managed to copy between two projects without any problems. Nice one

Answer (score 9):

Bucket names in GCS are unique across all of your projects.  For example, Project1 and Project2 cannot both have buckets named 'images', although they can each have folders inside those buckets named 'images'.

This can seem misleading because gsutil may ask you to select a project to work with.  For the copy command, this selection can be disregarded.

`gsutil cp gs://bucket1/obj gs://bucket2/obj`

will allow you to copy an object in Project1/bucket1 to Project2/bucket2

Answer (score 9):

If you have a key or a service account that gives you access to both projects, it is super simple and works at light speed to use gsutils.

This is what I did from my local mac and synced terabytes of data in minutes (yes, minutes and not hours)

```
gsutil -m rsync -r gs://my/source/project/bucket/files/ gs://my/target/project/bucket/directory/
```

The key here is to use `-m` flag.

Check official docs at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync for more details.

Comment: This works very well, and very quickly since -m makes it run in parallel and it uses rsync so it copies efficiently not moving unchanged files. You do need an account with the right privilege on both projects as expected.

Comment: Not sure why this has been voted down, this is the most efficient way to do it quickly. gsutil rsync makes the content of a target folder identical to the content of a source folder by copying, updating or deleting any file in the target folder that has changed in the source folder.

Comment: The link above include "]" so it will be broken if you click it. Here is the right one: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync

Comment: Yup, it's an exaggeration to say that this method does in minutes that `cp` will take hours to do.

Answer (score 4):

As per the docs [Moving Buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/moving-buckets#storage-create-bucket-gsutil).

You can simply use `gsutil`.

```sh
gsutil cp -r gs://[SOURCE_BUCKET]/* gs://[DESTINATION_BUCKET]
```

**note:** _if using `zsh`. Make sure you wrap your source bucket in single quotes. Because zsh will attempt to expand the wildcard before gsutil sees it. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075182/gsutil-returning-no-matches-found).

You can find the link for `gsutil` in your storage browser Overview tab.

Answer (score 3):

Using Google Cloud Shell

Go to the first project which has the bucket you wanted to copy 
`gcloud config set project [PROJECT1 ID]`

Made a directory you can mount that bucket to 
`mkdir test`

Mount the bucket to the directory 
`gcsfuse [BUCKET1] test`

Switch to the second project, which had the bucket you wanted to populate 
`gcloud config set project [PROJECT2 ID]`

Copy the contents of the new folder to the second bucket 
`gsutil cp -r /home/user/test gs://[BUCKET2]`