# How to export all firebase storage buckets from project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, storage

I need to export a nontrivial amount of data from one Firebase project to another.  I have roughly 100 storage buckets that I need to transfer from one project to another.

I've found this documentation that covers exporting Firestore data:   https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import.

Most articles and SO posts involving exporting data seem to follow the model described here. It'd be a serious undertaking to individually copy data from each bucket into a separate backup bucket.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out gsutil is the way to go on this one.  It was a very speedy process.  To copy data from one project to the other one, I ran a command that looked like this.

```
gsutil -m  cp  -r -n  gs://[PROJECT 1 ID].appspot.com/* gs://[PROJECT 2 ID].appspot.com
```

I had to add the appropriate permissions in IAM.  This post helped.
[How can I move data directly from one Google Cloud Storage project to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31049535/how-can-i-move-data-directly-from-one-google-cloud-storage-project-to-another/56982037#56982037).