# GCP How to copy files automatically from Project A to Project B every monday?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, copy, google-cloud-storage

GCP is a new thing for me but i want to know if it's possible to copy a specific file (e.g : myFiles.csv) from a bucket in the project A to a bucket in the project B every monday at 6.00 am ?

I need it because myFiles.csv is overwritten every Monday and i need to share it with the project B.

Comment: Can you have a look at a transfer service - https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/overview are there any reasons it cannot be used in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Storage transfer` :
https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-transfers#google-cloud-console

With this service, you can select the source and destination bucket and scheduling options, every day in your case.

[image]

**Source bucket project GCP A :**

[image]

In this example, I selected a folder `team_league` in a `bucket` called `mazlum_dev`

In the `prefix` field, I added the name of the file I want to transfer `input_team_slogans.json`

You have to put your file name for your job.

**Destination bucket project B :**

[image]

You have to select the output folder of your destination bucket.

**Sheduling options :**

[image]

You can also use the `GCloud` sdk if needed with `gsutil` :

```
gsutil cp gs://your_bucket_project_a/your_file gs://your_bucket_project_b/output/
```

But you have to find a way to cron this script every day, that's why I recommend the first solution because everything is native and integrated for your need.

Comment: Your answer is off to a good start but does not show how to copy a specific file as specified in the question.

Comment: Thanks John, I didn't want my bucket names appear in the image, but you are right, I am going to add this detail in my answer.

Comment: @JohnHanley I updated my answer, don't hesitate if you have other propositions. Thanks again

Comment: Thank you @Mazlum Tosun
It seems that it's exactly what i need. I will try this solution by monday at the latest.

Comment: Thank you @Mazlum tosun, it's the perfect solution that i needed !

Comment: Great :), I am glad it's worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps :

Click on this  Web console link [Storage > Transfer](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/storage/browser/transfer) to create a [new transfer](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-transfers#google-cloud-console). Then Select the source bucket you want to copy from ex.Project A.  So once you go to the destination part of the transfer form, you can write/paste the target bucket (Ex. Project B) right in its text input. Even if that bucket is from another project. It will show you a green icon once the target has been verified as being an existing bucket. You can continue the form again to finalize your setup.

Once you start the transfer from the form, you can follow its progress by hitting the refresh button on top of the console.

As the bucket identifiers are globally unique ([this is key to the solution](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming-buckets#considerations)).

Refer this [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31049535/how-can-i-move-data-directly-from-one-google-cloud-storage-project-to-another/39008449#39008449) for more information.